# In WCF Data Services, can I enclose a list of references to another entity while creating a new object?

Tags: rest, wcf-data-services, odata

I have a table Article, a table Tag and a joint table to associate a tag to an article.

While creating a new Article, by sending a POST request to /Service.svc/Articles, is it possible to enclose in the JSON object a list of Tag ids to be associated?

Something like:

```
{
  title: "My article title",
  text: "The content:",
  Tags: [ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 } ]
}
```

If not can I send the list of tags in one request? For example:

```
/Service.svc/Articles(1)/Tags

[ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 } ]
```

Or do I have to make as many requests as they are tags?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify just the links by POST/PUT/DELETE to the $links URL as described here: http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/operations#CreatingLinksbetweenEntries
The samples there use ATOM/XML, but the respective JSON format is also possible.
To send multiple operations to the server in one request (to save the roundtrips) you can create a batch request as described here:
http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/batch

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought it was possible to enclose the reference to an entry while creating another as the OData documentation says: "A new Link between two Entries can be established by referencing one Entry during creation or modification of another Entry". It says "one" though, how does that work in a many-to-many relationship then?

Comment: The many-to-many can't be modified with the link element in the posted entry since the href of the link doesn't uniquely identify all the entities on the other side of the relationship.

Comment: To modify the many-to-many you need to issue a separate request (or possibly multiple) to the $links URLs.